# Lua: How do I replace two or more repeating "?" characters with an empty string?

Tags: regex, lua

I've tried something like the following:

```
local str = "???"
string.gsub(str, "(??)*", "")
```

but it removes all '?' characters.  I'd like single '?' not replaced but more than one '?' replaced with an empty string.

Eg:

```
"?" = not replaced
"??" = replaced
"???" = replaced
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try pattern `"%?%?+"`

Comment: Yes, "%?%?+" was correct @EgorSkriptunoff.  See below for correct answer.  You should have entered your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question marks are magic in Lua patterns: they mean [0 or 1 occurrence](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) of the previous class.
Lua escapes magic characters in patterns with the `%` character.

The correct pattern for your task is `%?%?+`, which means an actual `?` character once, followed by one or more actual `?` characters (see the `+` modifier in the link above).

This code

```
function test(s)
    print(s,s:gsub("%?%?+","-"))
end

for n=0,4 do
    test("["..string.rep("?",n).."]")
end
```

outputs

```
[]      []      0
[?]     [?]     0
[??]    [-]     1
[???]   [-]     1
[????]  [-]     1
```

where `-` shows where replacements were made.