# Lua: How do I place something between two or more repeating characters in a string?

Tags: regex, lua

This question is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317085/lua-how-do-i-replace-two-or-more-repeating-characters-with-an-empty-string), but my task is to place something, in my case the dash, between the repeating characters, for example the question marks, using the `gsub` function.

Example:

```
"?"   =  "?"
"??"  =  "?-?"
"???  =  "?-?-?"
```

Comment: Qs :gsub( '?', '?-' ) :sub( 1, -2 )

Comment: @Doyousketch2, it's satisfactory, though it places a dash with a single question mark if there's any character except another question mark exists after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test(s)
    local t=s:gsub("%?%?","?-?"):gsub("%?%?","?-?")
    print(#s,s,t)
end

for n=0,10 do
    test(string.rep("?",n))
end
```

Comment: It works. But why doesn't single `gsub` work this way? I tried it before and it worked only once or so.

Comment: @lemonowo not once, just on nonoverlapping matches. See also eg. `("qwertyuio"):gsub("..", print)`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using LPeg:

```lua
local lpeg = require 'lpeg'

local head = lpeg.C(lpeg.P'?')
local tail = (lpeg.P'?' / function() return '-?' end) ^ 0

local str = lpeg.Cs((head * tail + lpeg.P(1)) ^ 1)

for n=0,10 do
    print(str:match(string.rep("?",n)))
end

print(str:match("?????foobar???foo?bar???"))
```

Answer (score -1):

This what i can came out with scanning each letter by letter

```
function test(str)
  local output = ""
  local tab = {}
  for let in string.gmatch(str, ".") do
    table.insert(tab, let)
  end
  local i = 1
  while i <= #tab do
    if tab[i - 1] == tab[i] then
      output = output.."-"..tab[i]
    else
      output = output..tab[i]
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
  return output
end
for n=0,10 do
  print(test(string.rep("?",n)))
end
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it looks too complex and it uses string concatenation inside a loop which can negatively impact on performance. I'm not that experienced but I think it's better to use `table.concat` at the end, and instead of `table.insert(tab, let)` you could use `tab[#tab + 1] = let`, and the same method instead of `output` string concatenation.

Comment: `table.insert(tab, let)` and `tab[#tab + 1] = let` is the same functionality so it ok to use `table.insert` also how string concatenation can affect performance

Comment: It makes an impact on performace because whenever you concatenate strings you are creating a new string and when you use `table.insert` you modify an already existing table.

Comment: it also remove the old string because it getting replaced by new string